WordPress Remove JS added from a plugin
I've tried several solutions found on here and can't seem to get this working...
Basically, I'm using a plugin that updated but the newest version of the JS it's including is breaking my site.  I want to stop it from loading this JS and I will just load it on my own in my theme.
I've tried using wp_deregister_script('knockout'); but it still loads the JS.  The only relevant reference to "knockout.js" I can find in the theme is this...
    $scripts = array(
        array(
            'handle'  => 'knockout',
            'src'     => $this->get_base_url() . '/js/built/knockout.js',
            'version' => $this->_version,
            'enqueue' => null,
        ),
    );

So I assumed I could just do the following BUT it doesn't work.
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_knockout_js', 99999 );

function remove_knockout_js() {
    wp_deregister_script('knockout');
}

Is there any other way to remove this JS file and add my own version?

Does this help? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189985/how-to-properly-dequeue-scripts-and-styles-in-child-theme

try using action wp_print_scripts
